# Java Servlet Session what should go inside and redirection

Tags: java, servlets

I was wondering what data should go into a session. Say I had a user object that had a list of objects that represent links to images. Should I save the username of the user object in the session and use that to query the db for the user object with the links to the images, or should I save the entire object, list included in the session and use that if no updates are needed? Is this a bad strategy?

I am new at this so I am sorry if this does not make any sense. Also is it possible to do encodeurl if the requestdispatcher is being insteand of sendredirect? It seems like if I use the request dispatcher I have to send the jessesion id in the cookie.

Comment: +1, interesting question. But please post the second paragraph as a second independent question

Comment: For the second question I was wondering if there was a way to encode the session id in the url if I am using the requestdispatcher and not redirectUrl

Answer (score 2):

Storing the full object graph in session:

#### Pros:

- **Faster** - everything is always in memory, as long as it fits there
- **Easier** - you are working with objects, no additional database interaction layer is needed

#### Cons:

- **Resource consumption** - your sessions will consume a lot of resources, especially if object graph is huge. One user having thousands of images will make your server crawl to its knees
- **Scalability** - it is much easier to distribute small sessions with easy to serialize objects
- **Consistency** - when the database is changed you must make sure that the HTTP session is updated as well. This can be painful

That being said you should keep the HTTP session as small as possible and when performance becomes a problem (frequent database queries) think about caching.

Comment: Thank you your answer was very insightful, i will take your advice into consideration.